# Python PIL library installer chrashing on Windows 7 Enterprise

Tags: python, installation, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to install PIL 1.1.7 library to my Python 2.7 installation, but the installer chrashes when I try to do this. I downloaded the installer from this page: [PIL library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/#pil117)

I downloaded **Python Imaging Library 1.1.7 for Python 2.7**

My system specs are: Windows 7 Enterprise, 64-bit. Here is what I see when I do the installation:

[image]

Any idea why this is happening? Thnx for any help =)

P.S. If you need any additional information, I'm happy to provide =)

**UPDATE**:

It might be something on my Python installation. I tried installing **Pillow** from here: [Python extensions](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pil) and I get the same problem...should I just reinstall Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just installed pil library using  " pip install pil " . Install pip on your system, its the best and easy method of install python libraries for both Windows as well as Linux .

[image: Pil succesfully instaled]